# Why the 'Input' used as a type when it should refer to a value? TS 2749

Tags: reactjs, typescript, input, compiler-errors

The format of the file is correct .tsx
And HTMLInputElement is not the right type that needs to be there instead of Input. I think it should be Input because it refers to the assigned value.
What is the problem with this code below at line 47, Col 28?

See the error message below:

'Input' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof Input'?  TS2749

```
    45 |   const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState<any>({})
    46 |   const [tags, setTags] = useState<string[]>([])
  > 47 |   const barcodeRef = useRef<Input>(null)
       |                             ^
    48 |   const imageInputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null)
    49 |   const formRef = useRef<FormInstance>(null)
    50 |
```

Comment: You probably have defined a variable named `Input` somewhere. Make sure that `Input` really refers to the type of your ref.

Answer (score 0):

Line 47 should likely be the same as line 48,

```
const barcodeRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null)
```

Comment: HTMLInputElement is assigned to another type. It should be Input. I don't understand this issue.

Comment: What kind of element is barcodeRef? What are you trying to accomplish? What is an Input in this context?